# Mysql - Order query by relevance without full-text method

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I want to know how can I achieve this.
I need to order a query by relevance but I cannot do that, I do not want to use the full-text + boolean mode, etc because I have a lot of records that do not appears this way (50%+ of regs) and so on, so I've create a query in a loop to search word by word and I exclude the irrelevant words by myself before doing the query, the result of the process for two words query is something like this:

```
SELECT UsrNames, UsrLastNames 
FROM user
WHERE 1 AND (UsrNames LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrLastNames LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrCI LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrEmail LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrRUC LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrCod LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrPhone LIKE '%FirstWord%'
            OR UsrNames LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrLastNames LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrCI LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrEmail LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrRUC LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrCod LIKE '%SecondWord%'
            OR UsrPhone LIKE '%SecondWord%') ORDER BY  UsrNames ASC 
 LIMIT 20
 OFFSET 0
```

It is right now in development, so the don't you care about the "WHERE 1" at the beginning.

Hope this great comunity could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will order by the number of matches:

```
ORDER BY IF(UsrNames LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrLastNames LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrCI LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrEmail LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrRUC LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrCod LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrPhone LIKE '%FirstWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrNames LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrLastNames LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrCI LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrEmail LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrRUC LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrCod LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0)
        + IF(UsrPhone LIKE '%SecondWord%', 1, 0) DESC,
    UsrNames ASC
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/892aa/6)

The `IF()` expressions convert each of the comparisons to a number and totals them. If you wanted, you could even make some fields more important in the ranking by giving them a higher value than `1`.

Comment: It didnt work, shows a sql syntax error, tryed with: ORDER BY  UsrNames LIKE '%FirstWord%' DESC, UsrLastNames LIKE '%FirstWord%' DESC,... and it works, not perfect but helped a bit. thank you

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data and the query you tried that got an error?

Comment: I've changed it to use `IF` to convert the comparison to 1 or 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can not see the change. What should I do?